# How to save changes from DropDownList to sql database?

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net, database

I edited a DataGrid column so the location is now a DropDownList, which works fine. It populates the DropDownList from the database.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Trailer Location">
    <itemtemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTrailerLoc" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTrailerLoc_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="hdlTrailerLoc" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("TrailerLocation")%>' />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

But when I change the value in the DropDownList I don't know how to save the changes made to the database.

```
protected void PopulateDDLs(DropDownList ddlTrailerLoc)
{
    DataSet dsTrailerLocation = DataUtils.GetAllGenSmall(Company.Current.CompanyID, "Description", "", 1, false, "Description", false, "TrailerLocationNOCODE", 0);
    if (dsTrailerLocation.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ddlTrailerLoc.DataSource = dsTrailerLocation;
        ddlTrailerLoc.DataValueField = "Description";
        ddlTrailerLoc.DataTextField = "Description";
         ddlTrailerLoc.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            ddlTrailerLoc.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("No Locations Entered", "0"));
        }
    }

protected void dgList_ItemCreated(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Header && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Pager && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            DropDownList ddlTrailerLocation = e.Item.FindControl("ddlTrailerLoc") as DropDownList;
            if (ddlTrailerLocation != null)
            {
                PopulateDDLs(ddlTrailerLocation);
                //set the value in dropdown
                HiddenField hdlTrailerLoc = e.Item.FindControl("hdlTrailerLoc") as HiddenField;
                if (hdlTrailerLoc != null)
                {
                    ddlTrailerLocation.SelectedValue = hdlTrailerLoc.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried creating this ddlTrailerLoc_SelectedIndexChanged method but the event doesn't run.

```
protected void ddlTrailerLoc_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList list = (DropDownList)sender;
    TableCell cell = list.Parent as TableCell;
    DataGridItem item = cell.Parent as DataGridItem;

    int selectedIndex = item.ItemIndex;
    string selectedItem = item.Cells[0].Text;
    // now save your work here and rebind the grid.
    Trailer.UpdateTrailer(int.Parse(TrailerID), Company.Current.CompanyID,
                                                txtTrailerReg.Text,
                                                ddlTrailerLocation.Text);
    ddlTrailerLocation.DataValueField = "Description";
    ddlTrailerLocation.DataTextField = "Description";
    ddlTrailerLocation.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Do a little [research on DropDownLists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wd7hsyy(v=vs.85).aspx) and if something isn't working, we can help.

Comment: I've tried creating a function for ddlTrailerLoc_SelectedIndexChanged but that didn't work

Comment: _What_ didn't work? The event never fired? The values were incorrect? Couldn't connect to the database? Insert didn't work?

Comment: The event never fired. I tried debugging it and it didn't run the method

Comment: Great! So add that to your question. Add what you tried that _didn't work_. You're on the right path.

Comment: Thank you. At least part of your problem is answered within the link in my first comment. The first bullet point under "To respond directly to changes in a list Web server control" goes into detail about it.

Comment: @j.f. ok the problem now is there is something wrong with the update statement

Answer (score 0):

Please add AutoPostBack="True" in dropdown. It will work

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTrailerLoc" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTrailerLoc_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Please write code as below

```
protected void ddlTrailerLoc_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlTrailerLoc=sender as DropDownList;
    if(ddlTrailerLoc!=null)
    {
         int trailerId=int.Parse(ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString());
         //Save selected value in Database 

    // now save your work here and rebind the grid.
    Trailer.UpdateTrailer(trailerId, Company.Current.CompanyID,
                                                txtTrailerReg.Text,
                                                ddlTrailerLoc.Text);
    ddlTrailerLocation.DataValueField = "Description";
    ddlTrailerLocation.DataTextField = "Description";
    ddlTrailerLocation.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Comment: I get error  Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String
on the line  Trailer.UpdateTrailer(int.Parse(TrailerID),

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format error for int trailerId = int.Parse(ddlTrailerLoc.SelectedValue.ToString());